# Html5 player supporting mp4 xvid avi flv?

Tags: html, html5-video

As i said in the question, i am looking for a html5 player which supports:

- `Avi`
- `mp4`
- `xvid`
- `flv`

  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't going to find a HTML5 player which supports the formats you listed. You can find a chart [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_video#Browser_support) showing which browsers support which codec. AVI and XVID aren't supported by any browser, you can however get around playing flv by using a flash player.